# MySQL Error - Unknown column 'xyz' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

I recently upgraded the MYSQL version from 4 to 5 and I get this error..

Error No : 1054
Error : Unknown column 'c.city' in 'on clause'

```
`SELECT b.expirydate, a.ben_changed, a.amlnotes, a.processdate, c.phone AS beneficiaryphone, cpstate.statename AS collectionpointstate, cpcity.cityname AS collectionpointcity, cp.agentname    AS  collectionpointname, cp.agentaddress AS collectionpointaddress, cp.agenttelephone AS collectionpointphoneno, b.postcode AS customerpostcode, co.countryname AS bencountryname,  st.statename AS benstatename, ct.cityname AS bencityname, a.depositbankname AS depositbankname, b.address AS customeraddress, b.phone AS customerphone, a.releasedate, a.releasedby,    a.collectiontype, b.mobile AS customermobile, c.mobile AS beneficiarymobile, a.releasemessage, a.releaseorder, a.amlnotes, bf.bankname, a.branchname, a.accountno, a.ordertime, h.agentname     AS payingagentname, a.cashcommission, d.agentname AS officename, a.orderdate, a.orderid, a.orderamount, a.agentcommission, e.username AS orderby, g.currencycode AS fromcurrency,   f.currencycode AS currency, a.exchangerate, a.benamount, b.surname AS customersurname, b.firstname AS customerfirstname, c.surname AS bensurname, c.firstname AS benfirstname, a.orderstatus,   a.saleid, a.benid, a.contactid
FROM contact_master b, ben_master c, agent_master d, sales_master a
LEFT JOIN agent_master cp ON a.collectionofficeid = cp.agentid
LEFT JOIN city_master cpcity ON cp.city = cpcity.cityid
LEFT JOIN state_master cpstate ON cp.state = cpstate.stateid
LEFT JOIN currency_master f ON a.currency = f.currencyid
LEFT JOIN city_master ct ON c.city = ct.cityid
LEFT JOIN state_master st ON c.state = st.stateid
LEFT JOIN country_master co ON c.country = co.countryid
LEFT JOIN currency_master g ON a.fromcurrency = g.currencyid
LEFT JOIN user_master e ON a.orderby = e.userid
LEFT JOIN payingagent_master h ON a.payingagent = h.agentid
LEFT JOIN bank_master bf ON a.bankname = bf.bankid
WHERE a.contactid = b.contactid
AND a.benid = c.benid
AND a.officeid = d.agentid
AND a.contactid =  '2'
AND orderdate & gt ; =  '2013-04-09'
AND orderdate & lt ; =  '2013-04-09'
AND a.orderby !=  'onlinewebsite'
ORDER BY orderdate, ordertime ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30`
```

Please Advise..

Thank You,

Comment: Your `ben_master` table doesn't have a field called `city`.

Comment: ben_master.city exist in your table??could you please check?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `there is no column named city in table ben_master`. please confirm.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply..
this same query works fine with MySQL 4 .. but MySQL 5
and yes.. the column city exists in the table..

Comment: What's the sql-type of colunm city of table ben_master? is it the same as ct.cityid ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to post the structrue of table ben_master?